# How to integrate the Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am currently trying to integrate the bootstrap datepicker, but for some reason it is not working at all. The datepicker is simply not showing like it should.

I have created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4hmuff8x/
It contains the js code of both the datepicker and bootstrap as well as the css for these.

To explain what I am doing, the following html code is the input where I want the datepicker:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 spacer-below-20">
                                <label>The date</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Of course I have written a bit of js, which should "link" the input tag to the datepicker:

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
                });
            });
            </script>
```

I really can't figure out why it is not working. I hope some of you can help me out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DId you added reference of moment.js ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the main JS file for Bootstrap...and for jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given fiddle , you are calling the below function before loading the js file into DOM.

`$('.datepicker').datepicker({
                        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
                });`

call the script after loading the script or on

`$(document).ready(function(){
//code to call 
})`

https://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/4hmuff8x/2/